# Python code works on cmd and VScode but not on powershell or pyinstaller

Tags: python, powershell

I have written a python script to save a book. It takes screenshots, turns pages(pyautogui click) and combines the screenshots into a PDF.

This is what happens on executing code in vscode:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> & C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/New folder/Windows_v1.py"
On page 1
On page 2
On page 3
On page 4
Combining PDF
PS C:\Users\Admin>
```

This is what happens in cmd

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New folder>python Windows_v1.py
On page 1
On page 2
On page 3
Combining PDF
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New folder>
```

This is what happens on powershell

```
PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Folder> python Windows_v1.py
On page 1
On page 2
```

...and it just stays there(tested for 15 minutes).

The script:

```
# Not in standard library- img2pdf, pyautogui, PIL
import img2pdf
import time
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pyautogui
import os

#Main window creation

# Top level window 
frame = tk.Tk() 
frame.title("Screenshot PDF maker") 
frame.geometry('400x400') 
frame.wm_attributes('-alpha',1)

# Transparent Button Creation 
def makeTrans():
    frame.update()
    frame.wm_attributes('-alpha',0.3)
    frame.update()
    
transButton = tk.Button(frame, 
    text = "Make window transparent for ease", 
    command = makeTrans)


# TextBox Creation 
inplabBookName = tk.Text(frame, 
    height = 2, 
    width = 20) 

inpSaveLoc = tk.Text(frame, 
    height = 2, 
    width = 20) 

inpPageNo = tk.Text(frame, 
    height = 2, 
    width = 20) 

# Create labels for main page
labBookName = tk.Label(frame, text = "Book name") 
labBookName.config(font =("Arial", 8)) 

labIns = tk.Label(frame, text = "Arrange and shape the window so that it covers the entire page.\n Do NOT include title bar") 
labIns.config(font =("Arial", 9)) 

labSaveLoc = tk.Label(frame, text = "Location") 
labSaveLoc.config(font =("Arial", 7)) 

labPageNum = tk.Label(frame, text = "Number of pages") 
labPageNum.config(font =("Arial", 7)) 

#Pack everything
labIns.pack()
transButton.pack()
labBookName.pack()
inplabBookName.pack()
labSaveLoc.pack()
inpSaveLoc.pack() 
inpSaveLoc.insert(tk.END, "D:\\Books")
labPageNum.pack() 
inpPageNo.pack()
frame.wait_visibility(frame)

#Next Button
var = tk.IntVar()
nextButton = tk.Button(frame, text="Next", command=lambda: var.set(10))
nextButton.pack()

nextButton.wait_variable(var)

#Perpare mouse detection screen

#Remove old elements
labIns.pack_forget()
transButton.pack_forget()
labBookName.pack_forget()
inplabBookName.pack_forget()
labSaveLoc.pack_forget()
inpSaveLoc.pack_forget() 
labPageNum.pack_forget() 
inpPageNo.pack_forget()
nextButton.pack_forget() 
frame.wm_attributes('-alpha', 1)

# Create labels
labMouseX = tk.Label(frame, text = "Mouse X") 
labMouseX.config(font =("Arial", 7)) 

labMouseY = tk.Label(frame, text = "Mouse Y") 
labMouseY.config(font =("Arial", 7))


#text inputs for mouse screen
inpmox = tk.Text(frame, 
    height = 2, 
    width = 20) 

inpmoy = tk.Text(frame, 
    height = 2, 
    width = 20) 

inpWait = tk.Text(frame, 
    height = 2, 
    width = 20) 

autoDetlabIns = tk.Label(frame, text = "Press the button and move your mouse over the Next Button to turn the page. \n The co-ords will be picked up 3 seconds after press.") 
autoDetlabIns.config(font =("Arial", 7)) 

waitlabIns = tk.Label(frame, text = "Seconds of delay it takes to change page after clicking")
waitlabIns.config(font =("Arial", 7)) 

startlabIns = tk.Label(frame, text = "This window will disappear. You do not need to move your mouse or press any key. \n When the PDF is ready, the program will close itself") 
startlabIns.config(font =("Arial", 7)) 
inpmoy.insert(tk.END, "1")

#buttons for mouse screen
def autodetmouse():
    time.sleep(3)
    temx, temy = pyautogui.position()
    inpmox.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    inpmoy.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    inpmox.insert(tk.END, temx) 
    inpmoy.insert(tk.END, temy)

autodet = tk.Button(frame, 
    text = "Auto detect mouse position", 
    command = autodetmouse)


#Pack everything for mouse screen
labMouseX.pack()
inpmox.pack()
labMouseY.pack()
inpmoy.pack()
autoDetlabIns.pack()
autodet.pack()
waitlabIns.pack()
inpWait.pack()
startlabIns.pack()

# Start button creation
var = tk.IntVar()
startButton = tk.Button(frame, text="Start", command=lambda: var.set(1))
startButton.pack()

frame.update_idletasks()
frame.update()

startButton.wait_variable(var)

 #Remove all elements and make transparent
labMouseX.pack_forget()
labMouseY.pack_forget()
autoDetlabIns.pack_forget()
autodet.pack_forget()
startlabIns.pack_forget()
startButton.pack_forget()

frame.update_idletasks()
frame.update()

frame.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0)

frame.update_idletasks()
frame.update()
#Main processing

def main():
    #Prepare variables for processing
    save_Loc = str(inpSaveLoc.get("1.0", "end-1c"))
    doc = inplabBookName.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    num_pages = int(inpPageNo.get("1.0", "end-1c"))
    waitTime = int(inpWait.get("1.0", "end-1c"))
    varInpMoY = int(inpmoy.get("1.0",'end-1c'))
    varInpMoX = int(inpmox.get("1.0",'end-1c'))
    
    inpmoy.pack_forget()
    imgs = []

    inpmox.insert(tk.END, "processing...") 

    #Fix all inputs
    save_Loc = save_Loc.rstrip('\\')
 
    if not os.path.exists(save_Loc):
        os.makedirs(save_Loc)
    
    os.makedirs(save_Loc + "/" + doc)
    pyautogui.moveTo(varInpMoX, varInpMoY) #so that cursor doesn't come in the way

    for pg_num in range(num_pages):
        print('On page', str(pg_num + 1))
        im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(frame.winfo_rootx(), frame.winfo_rooty(), frame.winfo_width(), frame.winfo_height()))
        finSavLoc = save_Loc + "/" + doc + "/" + str(pg_num + 1) + ".png"
        im.save(finSavLoc)
        imgs.append(finSavLoc)
        time.sleep(waitTime)

        #Flip page
        pyautogui.moveTo(varInpMoX, varInpMoY)
        pyautogui.click()

    print("Combining PDF")  
    inpmox.insert(tk.END, "Combinig PDF...") 
    with open(save_Loc + "/" + doc + "/" + doc +".pdf" ,"wb") as f:
        f.write(img2pdf.convert(imgs))
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have tried:

1. Rebooting
2. Re-installing all the required pip modules

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Could it be because of your version of Python? Vsc and cmd may be use different versions of python. You should check it and try to run same version of vsc's python .

Comment: cmd: Python 3.9.2 (tags/v3.9.2:1a79785, Feb 19 2021, 13:44:55) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

powershell: Python 3.9.2 (tags/v3.9.2:1a79785, Feb 19 2021, 13:44:55) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out the auto-clicker was the problem with PowerShell. Whenever it used to click on the PowerShell command line, it paused. Fixed using this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/205898